# In objective c, how to do AES256 encryption using md5 doubled as the key?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, aes, md5

I have been trying to replicate an android code which does AES256 encryption using md5 doubled as the key. Everything seems to be fine but the values after the encryption doesn't seem to be the same. Please go through my below codes

Android :-

```
public static String encrypt(String key, String value) {
    try {
        byte[] keyArr = new byte[32];
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] hash = md.digest(key.getBytes("US-ASCII"));//in md5 function 1st line
        keyArr = arrayCopy(0, hash, 0, keyArr, 16);//in md5 function 1st for loop
        keyArr = arrayCopy(0, hash, 15, keyArr, 16);//in md5 function 2nd for loop
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyArr, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        String encryptedB64 = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
        return encryptedB64;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
private static byte[] arrayCopy(int sourceIndex,byte[] source,int targetIndex,byte[] target,int transferSize){
    if(!(transferSize >0))
        return null;
    if(sourceIndex>=0 && sourceIndex < source.length){
        int transferCnt=0;
        int i=sourceIndex;
        for(int j=targetIndex;;j++,i++){
            if(targetIndex>=target.length || sourceIndex>=source.length || (++transferCnt>transferSize)){
                break;
            }
            target[j] = source[i];
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
    return target;
}
```

iOS objective-c

```
+ (NSString *) getFalconEncryptedValueForKey:(NSString *)theKey forString:(NSString *)theString
{
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
    NSData *rawData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *md5Key = [self md5:theKey];
    [md5Key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger dataLength = [rawData length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [rawData bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        NSString* encrypted64 = [tempData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];//Even i have tried base 64 encding with other options available
        return encrypted64;
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}


+ (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
//    const char * pointer = [self UTF8String];
    const char *cStr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), result );

    NSMutableString *md5String = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [md5String appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [md5String appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];

    return md5String;
    //for 32 byte. md5 produces only 16 byte info. we are replicating it again to make it 32 byte for aes256
}
```

Any kind of direction in what I have done wrong will be really helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Without the implementation of `arrayCopy` this is pure guesswork.

Comment: Is this what you meant -- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=641

Comment: This code has several issues: 1. probably uses a 128 bit key and stretches it to 256 bit without any additional security. 2. if `key` is actually a password, then simple hashing is not enough. Use PBKDF2 or similar. 3. `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` likely uses ECB mode which is quite [insecure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022). 4. There is no authentication of ciphertexts, so an attacker might alter the ciphertexts without you detecting it. Use an authenticated mode like GCM or apply HMAC to the ciphertexts.

Comment: No, that's something else.

Comment: Actually java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=641 that is the function that has been used. 
Also its a code written by a third party vendor and I don't have a say on it. No, key is not a password. Its an encrypted string.
Can you please help me to spot where I have missed on converting the code?

Comment: `arrayCopy` is not `System.arraycopy`, because the signature is completely different. Also, the values used for `arrayCopy` look strange. Particularly, the `15` in `arrayCopy(0, hash, 15, keyArr, 16);` probably doesn't what you think it does. Please first figure out what the code is doing.

Comment: Add test values, use hex for binary, the values just prior to and just after encryption. In other words a [mcve]. You might well find your problem just by looking for the differences between the two implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AES256 encryption using md5 *doubled* as the key

No, that's not the case.

In Android, the last byte of the first `hash` in `keyArr` is overwritten by the second `hash` (more precisely the first byte of the second `hash`). Therefore, the last byte of `keyArr` is always 0.

I'm not fluent in Objective-C, but I think, this should do it:

```
NSMutableString *md5String = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH-1; i++)
    [md5String appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [md5String appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
[md5String appendFormat:@"%02x",0];
```

(Btw, `arrayCopy` can produce an IndexOutOfBoundsException despite its numerous checks).

Of course, this produces a Hex-encoded string with a length of 64 characters. This is not what you want. Instead, you should produce actual bytes of length 32.

Correct code (by OP)

```
+ (NSString *) getEncryptedValueWithKey:(NSString *)theKey forString:(NSString *)theString
{
    NSData *rawData = [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    unsigned char md5Buffer[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
    memset(md5Buffer, 0, kCCKeySizeAES256+1);
    const char *cStr = [theKey UTF8String];

    // do md5 hashing
    CC_MD5(cStr, CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, md5Buffer);

    unsigned char lastChar = md5Buffer[15];
    for (NSInteger i = 15; i <= 30; i++) {
        md5Buffer[i] = md5Buffer[i-15];
    }
    md5Buffer[30] = lastChar;
    //MD5 key obtaining end

    NSUInteger dataLength = [rawData length];
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCOptionECBMode, md5Buffer, kCCKeySizeAES256, NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */, [rawData bytes], dataLength, /* input */ buffer, bufferSize, /* output */ &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
        NSString* encrypted64 = [tempData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];//Even i have tried base 64 encding with other options available
        return encrypted64;
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: wow, nice find...so it seems what they said and what they have done is different. lemme try with this change

Comment: Nope, still it doesnt match with the value they send. I must be missing something very important in the conversion.

Comment: The other possible issue that I see is that you're producing a Hex-encoded string in obj-c (I'm not entirely sure what `appendFormat:@"%02x"` does), but you actually need the binary key. You need to decode the Hex-encoded string at some point before using it for encryption.